# Elasticsearch filter via number of mentions

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I am trying to write a query which will return me articles about certain keywords but I want the articles to only show if the the given keyword is mentions 5 times in the articles I am using following query But no result

```
  {
   "query":{

      "multi_match":{
         "query":"Apple",
         "operator":"AND",
         "fields":[
            "Text"
         ]

      }
      ,"min_term_freq" : 5
   },
   "sort":{
      "Date":{
         "order":"desc"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe there is any min_term_freq option as you have listed.
But then you can use scripting in filter to achieve the same -

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "_index['Text']['apple'].tf() > 5"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your query is working fine but if I  change the word from apple to any other it doesn't work.

Comment: It should be an exisitng term ... What other term did you try >

Comment: I think i got the problem this query is not accepting two words like, tim took. So how do I solve that?

Comment: This only accepts tokenized terms like tim or took , and not "tim took"

Comment: Write an AND condition _index['Text']['time'].tf() > 5 &&  _index['Text']['took'].tf() > 5

Comment: The query is working fine now but it is not sorting data as per time